# The correct time to set TCP_NODELAY?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I'm writing a TCP proxy and want to disable Nagle algorithm by set TCP_NODELAY.

There are two kinds of socket:

1. socket from `accept()` call. (client -> proxy)
2. socket from `socket()` call. (proxy -> server)

So i'd like to know what is the correct time to set TCP_NODELAY for these two kinds socket?

Can i set TCP_NODELAY immediately after `accept()` or `socket()` call?

I checked [man 7 tcp](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html) but there is no answer :(

Comment: Sure, why not? Have you tried it? I don't see any reason to wait. As soon as you accept or connect is as good a time as any. If you need it, presumably you need it for the duration.

Comment: Well, considering that you need a socket descriptor in order to set `TCP_NODELAY`, it stands to reason that you can't set it *before* calling `accept()`/`socket()`, so obviously you have to set it *after* calling them. Once you have a socket descriptor, you can set `TCP_NODELAY` on it at *any* time.

Comment: @Remy: If you set TCP_NODELAY after a send, does the stack (A) immediately notice (a) the change and (b) that something is already buffered and so (B) transmit what has been accumulated?

Comment: @user15972 I would imagine that is implementation-defined behavior. But I suspect it won't take effect until the next send.

Answer (score 2):

You can set TCP_NODELAY immediately after accept() or socket() call. Nagle is just a flag in the TCP source code, once you set it, it will affect.

Comment: Which does that mean: {(A) Nagle is just a flag in the TCP source code, once you set it, it will affect future SENDs. (B) Nagle is just a flag in the TCP source code, once you set it, it will affect and trigger action if anything is already buffered.} I suspect the answer is (A).